# Total Gaussian curvature equal to $4\pi$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces, curvature

> I need to see for which $S$ connected, orientable (and compact) surfaces $\iint_{S} |K| dA=4\pi$, where $K$ means Gaussian curvature.

---

I think that it is only true if $S$ is a sphere. I have done the following:

We define $$S^{+}=\{p \in S: K(p)\geq 0\},S^{-}=\{p \in S: K(p)\leq 0\}. $$
So
$$
\iint_S |K| dA= \iint_{S^{+}} K dA+ \iint_{S^{-}} (-K) dA,
$$ which implies
$$
\iint_{S^{+}} K dA= \iint_S |K| dA\ \underbrace{+\iint_{S^{-}} K dA}_{\leq 0}\leq \iint_S |K| dA.
$$

Apart from that, $$\iint_S |K| dA = A(\mathbb{n}(S))\geq A(\mathbb{S^2})=4\pi $$

---

**Note**:A() means surface and n normal vector.

---

So $\iint_{S^{+}} K dA \geq 4\pi. $
Because of that, if we suppose that 
$$
\iint_S K dA = 4\pi \implies 4\pi = \iint_S |K| dA = \iint_{S^{+}} K dA
$$

So we have that $K(p)\geq 0$, $\forall p \in S$.

I want to see that $K$ is, in fact, constant but I don't know how to prove it... I would really thank some help.

Comment: You should check out Chern/Lashof's "On the total curvature of immersed manifolds," Am. J. Math. **79** (1957), 306-318, as well as the sequel in Michigan Math. J. **5** (1958), 5-12.

Comment: I think you switched a sign, it should be $\iint_{S^{+}} K dA \leq \iint_S |K| dA$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For surfaces with everywhere positive curvature, an easy answer comes from the Gauss-Bonnet theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem) which says that this integral is $2\pi \chi(S)$, so that the Euler characteristic, $\chi$, must be $2$. The only compact orientable surface with Euler characteristic $2$ is the sphere.

Gauss-Bonnet also tells you that for *any* smooth embedding of a sphere in 3-space, you get the integrated curvature is $4\pi$, so it's true even for a non-spherical ellipsoid, so your conjecture that $K$ must be constant is false.

====
For surfaces with both positive and negative curvature parts, you know that
$$
\iint K \le \iint |K|
$$
which says that no surface with Euler characteristic greater than 2 can have the desired property...but since there are no compact orientable surface with $\chi > 2$, that doesn't tell us much.

So I guess that this answer doesn't really get you where you want to go, alas.

Comment: It seems that you are answering the question about $\int _S K dA$ instead of $\int_S |K|dA$?

Comment: IIRC, OP's integrand is $|K|\, dA$, so one has to assume non-negative curvature to apply Gauss-Bonnet in genus $0$, and a nonpositive-curvature surface of genus $2$ also satisfies their condition. By a continuity argument there are examples of genus $1$, as well.

Comment: You're both correct. I totally missed the $|\cdot|$ signs. So I guess this is an answer for an everywhere-positive-curvature surface only. I'll edit.